# algorithm to tell if an npm package is treeshakable

Tags: javascript

I've been looking at the [agadoo](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/agadoo) package that tries to determine if a package is treehshakable.

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/agadoo/blob/master/index.js), this is the bit where it decides the answer

```
const nodes = ast.body.filter(node => {
  return node.type !== 'ImportDeclaration';
});

return {
  shaken: nodes.length === 0
};
```

So if I have something like an enum, which rollup will compile to a `var` then this will fail treeshaking.

Is this a good way of determining if a package is treeshakable?